# How Should I Format Dates in SAS from Strings to Numeric

Tags: date, sas, format

I am trying to convert a string to a numeric in SAS.  Currently, it looks like 05/23/2007.  My code so far is

```
Data Data2;
   Set Data1;
   Input(Date, mmddyy10w.);
   If Date > '07/15/2009'd;
 run;
```

I get an error saying that the format mmddyy10w. cannot be recognized.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: is your initial date variable is character

Answer (score 2):

Correct informat to read date in the scenario is mmddyy10., date literal should be like '14Jul2009'd. as shown in below example

```
 Data Data2;
 date= Input('07/15/2009',mmddyy10.);
 format date mmddyy10.;
 If Date > '14Jul2009'd;
 run;
```

below is the link, which gives good idea format and informats of dates in SAS.
https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings15/1334-2015.pdf